# Jquery how to execute commands appended with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm loading the content of a document into a div when I click one item of the menu. This foreign document contains jQuery commands. But is not running.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {    
    $("ul.subnav li a").click(function() {
            link = $(this).attr("href");
            $.ajax(link).done(function(data) {
                $("#div-page").html(data);
            });

            return false;
        });
});
```

In the document that will be loaded there is more jQuery commands like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        // get lista de estados
        $.ajax("../php/get_lista_estados.php").done(function(data) {
            $("#estados").append(data);
        });

        $("#estados").change(function() {
            id = $(this).val();
            // get lista de estados
            $.ajax("../php/get_lista_municipios.php?id=" + id).done(function(data) {
                $("#municipios").html(data);
            });
        });

    });
```

But when I load this document into div the commands don't run. Do I speak clear?

Comment: Javascript loaded with ajax will generally not be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to jQuery and Ajax combined - it is important to understand how JavaScript is being implemented on DOM while script loads.

The reason why you are seeing answers suggesting using `$.getScript()` or to add `<script src="your.js"></script>` is because, once DOM is loaded - then that's it.  If you wanted addition functions to be fired as long as it is coming from external script via ajax, just like what you are trying to do.  You are attempting to load new function to 'already-loaded' DOM - and it's not how it works.

If you want any functions to respond to the ajax injection, then you need to have your script to be among those that get preloaded when DOM is run.  So, that's how `$.getScript()` comes into the picture.

Usually, with that kind of injection you want to do, you will want to use `$.getScript()` to fetch your javascript functions / definitions, meanwhile your ajax to get/post the script that contains your HTML structures.  You will be able to do this fancy injection in this method and play it around with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load and run it. Read the jQuery docs for more info

Example:

```
$.getScript("test.js", function(){
    alert("Running test.js");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("ul.subnav li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    link = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
      url: link,
      dataType: "script"
    }).done(function(data){
      // No need to append data as the script has already been loaded and run.
      // $("#div-page").html(data);
      // Do any other stuff here..
    });
  });

});
```